# How to align arrays in the heap?

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory, simd, memory-alignment

I do some operations on array using `SIMD`, so I need to have them aligned in memory. When I place arrays on the `stack`, I simply do this and it works:

```
#define BUFFER_SIZE 10000
alignas(16) float approxFreqMuls_Float[BUFFER_SIZE];
alignas(16) double approxFreqMuls_Double[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

But now I need to allocate more memory (such as 96k `double`s, or more): so I think the `heap` is the way; but when I do this:

```
int numSteps = 96000;
alignas(16) float *approxFreqMuls_Float = new float[numSteps];
alignas(16) double *approxFreqMuls_Double = new double[numSteps];
```

It thrown error on `ostream`. Not really sure about the message (I'm on `MSVC`, nothing appair).

How would you allocate aligned arrays on `heap`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heap allocations are aligned to the maximum native alignment by default, so as long as you don't need to over-align, then you don't need to do anything in particular to align it.

If you do need over-alignment, for some reason, you can use the aligned new syntax `new (std::align_val_t(16)) float[numSteps];` (or `std::aligned_alloc` which is in the `malloc` family of functions and the memory must therefore be `free`d rather than `delete`d).

If you don't have C++17, then you need to allocate `size + align - 1` bytes instead if `size`, and `std::align` the pointer - or use a non-standard aligned allocation function provided on your target platform.

Comment: `Heap allocations are aligned to the maximum native alignment by default` what does it means this? Shouldn't align to 16 using SIMD? i.e. __mm_load_pd https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE2&text=_mm_load&expand=3287 (mem_addr must be aligned on a 16-byte boundary or a general-protection exception may be generated.)

Comment: In fact, If I remove the align, it crash as well :)

Comment: @markzzz It means that (regardless of the type given to `new`), the memory will be aligned sufficiently for any and all types except those that use `alignas` with larger values than `alignof(std::max_align_t)` i.e. types that are over-aligned. If max native alignment is 16, then you're all good. If it is less, then you need over-alignment. If you need specific alignment and don't know the native alignment, then using aligned allocation is a safe choice.

Comment: how can I check the "max native alignment"?

Comment: @markzzz using `alignof(std::max_align_t)`.

Comment: that print 8. So I think I need to `over-align`.

Comment: `float *approxFreqMuls_Float = static_cast<float*>(_mm_malloc(sizeof(float) * numSteps, 16));` + `_mm_free(approxFreqMuls_Float);` seems to works nice on MSVC...